# I am implement web push chrome notification in node js with payload concept. But I'm getting message is "the site is updating in the background"

Tags: google-chrome, payload

I am trying to implementing chrome push notification but I am getting some message again and again.

I'm also not able to find how this message is coming.But my payload message is different.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you post the code you're using? It's always easier for people to provide help when there is a specific code example to work with.

Answer (score 0):

That message is displayed when your service worker receives a push but you don't show a notification in the push event.

A common mistake is not returning the promise from showNotification into event.waitUntil(), like so:

```
self.addEventListener('push', event => {
  event.waitUntil(
    self.registration.showNotification('title', {
      body: 'body'
    })
  );
});
```